# How do I solve Golang filepath.walkfunc problem?

Tags: csv, go

I'm trying to solve a task where I must to find one file with data in CSV format among other files with similar names and same size and print a number on 5th row 3rd column (indexes 4 and 2)
So I wrote this code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

var s [][]string

func walkfunc(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    buf, err1 := os.Open(path)
    if err1 == nil {
        var err2 error
        r := csv.NewReader(buf)
        s, err2 = r.ReadAll()
        if err2 == nil {
            fmt.Printf("found: %v", s[4][2])
        }
    }
    defer buf.Close()
    return nil
}
func main() {
    const root = "./task/"
    if err := filepath.Walk(root, walkfunc); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

And I got this in output

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup
GOPATH=/usr/local/go/bin #gosetup
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /private/var/folders/j2/ybr0drz13yq31dc67zmvkb1w0000gn/T/GoLand/___go_build_qwasd3_go /Users/user/Downloads/zadacha/qwasd3.go #gosetup
/private/var/folders/j2/ybr0drz13yq31dc67zmvkb1w0000gn/T/GoLand/___go_build_qwasd3_go
panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 3

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.walkfunc({0x14000018120?, 0x0?}, {0x14000098d88?, 0x10247fe40?}, {0x0?, 0x0?})
        /Users/user/Downloads/zadacha/qwasd3.go:23 +0x28c
path/filepath.walk({0x14000018120, 0xe}, {0x1024c9cf8, 0x140000685b0}, 0x1024c9338)
        /usr/local/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:433 +0xd0
path/filepath.walk({0x10248d4a8, 0x7}, {0x1024c9cf8, 0x140000684e0}, 0x1024c9338)
        /usr/local/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:457 +0x1fc
path/filepath.Walk({0x10248d4a8, 0x7}, 0x1024c9338)
        /usr/local/go/src/path/filepath/path.go:520 +0x6c
main.main()
        /Users/user/Downloads/zadacha/qwasd3.go:37 +0x30

Process finished with the exit code 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was trying to run this code on MacBook.
The needed file contains table with numbers and I need to print a number on 5th row and 3rd column.

Comment: Handle the case where the file does not have the expected number of rows and columns:  `if len(s) < 5 || len(s[4]) < 3 { do something }`

Comment: I know for sure that the file I need has the required number of rows and columns. All other files have non-CSV data, so they don't have rows or columns at all.

Comment: Add this before the line that panics: `if len(s) < 5 || len(s[4]) < 3 { fmt.Println(path) }`.  Confirm that the printed filename is what you expect and that the file contains the expected number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

As other comments have pointed out, you need to check each CSV to make sure it's actually as big as you expect it to be.  You could also add a simple check to try and make sure it's a CSV file before opening it by looking for a ".csv" extension.

Though, to directly address your error... The CSV reader may be able to interpret a plain txt file as CSV and not return an err, like:

```golang
buf := strings.NewReader(`A regular text file with 3 lines.
Line2
Line3
`)

r := csv.NewReader(buf)
records, err := r.ReadAll()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("could not read all of CSV file!")
    return err
}

fmt.Println(records)
```

prints:

```
[[A regular text file with 3 lines.] [Line2] [Line3]]
```

Just assuming that it's a CSV with the correct number of rows and columns:

```golang
fmt.Println("found", records[4][2])
```

gives the panic message you shared:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 3
```

You at least need to check that your CSV has 5 rows, and if it does, then check if the 5th row has 3 columns before you try to read that *field*:

```golang
if len(records) < 5 {
    fmt.Println(path, "does not have 5 rows")
    return nil
}

if len(records[4]) < 3 {
    fmt.Println(path, "5th row does not have 3 columns")
    return nil
}

fmt.Println("found", records[4][2])
```

You could also do, inside your walkfunc, a basic check of the file path itself to see if it looks like a CSV:

```golang
if strings.ToLower(path[len(path)-4:]) != ".csv" {
    fmt.Println(path, "is not a CSV")
    return nil
}
```

I show all this code, plus a fully worked/integrated example [in this Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/tZAPHKC4m7T).